# React native base components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In react native:

How to create a component that extends another component rather than extending basic component from react

So instead of:

```
export default class XXX extends Component {
```

I need to create a Class `Base`

```
export default class XXX extends Base {
```

Where

```
export default class Base extends Component {
```

the whole idea is to create a `Base` component to use it as base class for all other components .

Comment: What exactly do you want to share between your components? Wouldn't it be better to use `context`? You can also extend `Component` with added functions.

Comment: for example i use "react native navigation" from wix and i need to add event listener to every screen component, in addtion to header icons and so on, so the idea is to create a base componenet that has these common things

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just you have to create a base component like below :-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class BaseReact extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    navigate=(name)=>{
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        navigate(name)
    }
}
```

Import that class inside your .js file:-

```
import BaseReact from '/*/*/*/*/*/*/screen/BaseReact';

export default class Splash extends BaseReact{

 constructor(props){
    super(props) 
  }
}
```

May be help to you to achieve your goal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, but it has some limitation. For example you can't override the parent methods. You can use `props`, send therm to parent component and call them in it. You can also use [Higher-Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html), add your logic to it and add render method for example to each extended component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, just as described in your question.

However, the React community favors composition over inheritance: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html